# how to merge header and sub header in csv in powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv, multiple-columns, columnsorting

Assume I have a sample.csv file with 2 rows with multiple columns as

```
Account,    Id, Date
Jan,    Dec,    Feb
```

now, I want to convert this file which consists single row, and change it in column order as output.csv in PowerShell scripting

```
Account,Id,Date,Jan,Feb,Dec
```

I tried many ways..

```
Import-Csv 'sample.csv' | Group-Object ID | ForEach-Object { [PsCustomObject]@{ Header = $_.Group.Dept -join ',' } } | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Can we see your attempts at this?

Comment: Import-Csv 'sample.csv' | Group-Object ID | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        
        Header = $_.Group.Dept -join ','
    }
} | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoTypeInformation

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put your attempts in there as [Formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text, not in a comment. Also can you do some formatting on the example lines you are showing us. Does that empty line in between really exist?

Comment: How do you know what data goes with the first header and what data goes with the 2nd header?  Maybe show more of the file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72452159/how-to-convert-mutiple-columns-to-mutiple-rows-in-powershell?noredirect=1#comment127991316_72452159

Answer (score 0):

Without going into detail on the issues you may encounter, here is what you can try:

```
@"
Account, Id, Date
Jan, Dec, Feb
one, two, three
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -PipelineVariable "Header" | Select-Object -First 1 | 
     ForEach-Object -Process {
        ($_.PSObject.Properties.Value, $Header[0].PSObject.Properties.Name | Write-Output) -join ","
    }
```

Tapping into the `PSObject` wrapper exposes additional properties not shown when piped to `Get-Member`. The main one we are after is the *Column Names* (`.Name`), and the *first* rows values (`.Value`). `Select-Object -First 1`, is to ensure only the first row is selected and not any other rows you may have. So, we join both property values and all that's left to do is export to a new csv.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72452159/how-to-convert-mutiple-columns-to-mutiple-rows-in-powershell?noredirect=1#comment127991316_72452159